# Remove progressbar border

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I remove the white border from the progress bar?

```
HWND hProgress = CreateWindowEx(0, PROGRESS_CLASS, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | PBS_SMOOTH, 29, 215, 492, 32, hwnd, (HMENU)0, hinst, NULL);
SendMessage(hProgress, PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, (LPARAM)RGB(12, 12, 12);
SendMessage(hProgress, PBM_SETBKCOLOR, 0, (LPARAM)RGB(13, 18, 18));
SetWindowTheme(hProgress, L" ", L" ");
```

Comment: Have you [enabled visual styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview)?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I have enabled but i tried to use SetWindowTheme(hProgress, L" ", L" "); but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Could you show a picture of what you expect vs. what you have? I'm not aware of any white border in progress bars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does what you're after. You probably want to modify the style before sending the progress bar any messages or you'll need to force it to redraw after.

```
long style = GetWindowLong(hProgress, GWL_EXSTYLE);
style &= ~WS_EX_STATICEDGE;
SetWindowLong(hProgress, GWL_EXSTYLE, style);
```

The top is without the changed style and the bottom is with the changed style.

[image]

Comment: Thanks thats what I need <3